# Force django to reopen database connection if lost

Tags: python, django, postgresql

In my Python-Django web application, sometimes the database it will disconnect (problems related to my test environment, not so much stable...) and my web-app give me this error:

```
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql/base.py", line 222, in create_cursor,
django.db.utils.InterfaceError: connection already closed,
    cursor = self.connection.cursor()
```

Now, how i can tell django to retry to open the connection and continue? it seems that django remains stuck at this point...

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no way to tell Django that it should retry on connection error. It's instead designed to simply fail on that one request. From [the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/databases/#connection-management):

> If any database errors have occurred while processing the requests, Django checks whether the connection still works, and closes it if it doesn’t. Thus, database errors affect at most one request; if the connection becomes unusable, the next request gets a fresh connection.

However, this shouldn't be a problem if you follow this advice in the documentation:

> If your database terminates idle connections after some time, you should set `CONN_MAX_AGE` to a lower value, so that Django doesn’t attempt to use a connection that has been terminated by the database server.

Comment: This does bed the question how it is possible though. I just ran into an issue with upgrading a DB and had to --force-restart the server a few times for it to start working again.